# Create element using JavaScript and use it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a new window using JavaScript and create element in that window,
when I try use that element by using id, I can't do that and take null value

```
var unit_Window = window.open("", '',"height=400,width=400,status=yes");   

unit_Window.document.write("<label id='title_ID'>title</label></center>");
```

now when I tried to get title value using id the value return is null

```
unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID');
```

Comment: you are using `getElementById`, it will return you the whole element itself not just title

Comment: try `unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID').innerHTML`

Comment: i know that @NirbhayKundan but i mean unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID') must return object element but currently return null

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yv4vojtq/ it is working as expected in chrome. Btw which browser you are using?

Comment: use `document.body.innerHTML` instead of `document.write`..

Comment: When i call it to first time error ocured but on other time its workin @NirbhayKundan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to your problem lies in timing. You need to be sure that the new window has finished loading before trying to modify its content.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396478/changing-popup-content).

Danny

Comment: I think that , but how i can know the popup window i create it finish loaded @allnodcoms

Comment: @RafatHajAli - Check the link I posted in my answer, or the link above.
You just need to put your DOM modification code in a callback that gets called when the new window's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get html of an element

```
unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID').innerHTML;
```

Only using `unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID');` will return the HTML element node itself not just the value.

For getting the HTML value of an element use `innerHTML` property of an element.

Comment: i know that @Murtaza Hussain but i mean unit_Window.document.getElementById('title_ID') must return object element but currently return null

Comment: Yes , my case its different @Murtaza Hussain

Comment: reading above comments from @allnodcoms post, you can set timeout for  half a second like this `setTimeout(function () {
        //execute your code. 
    }, 500);`

Comment: Thank You @Murtaza Hussain , time is  problem , but now succesd