# JavaScript: window.open external link and autologin

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a script in JS which would allow me to open (probably many) new windows to external sites (e.g. facebook) and autocomplete login and password (eventually - just login) with given creditentials.

**Note**: I don't care about security, it's just an *inner-use* script.

Basing on W3S I made something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="open.js">
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

and:

```
var fb = window.open('https://facebook.com');
if(fb) {
    fb.onload = function() {
        fb.document.getElementById('email').value = 'what';
        fb.document.getElementById('pass').value = 'ever';
        fb.document.getElementById('loginbutton').click();
    }
} else {
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

But all these do is open given site in a new tab.

I'm completely new to JS and HTML, so please explain like I'm five.

**edit**:
Ok, I've learnt thet it's impossible to set external domain's values using only JS and HTML (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there any quick way (code snippet would be most appreciated) to do so? I found some info and made a user's extension to chrome (not working so don't bother pasting the code), yet still have no idea how to implement this to many *new windows*  or generally - how tf should I do this... Any help, please?

Comment: Javascript cannot be executed across domains -- since your host is not facebook.com, it is blocked from getting elements from facebook's DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing popup content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396478/changing-popup-content)

Comment: @WillP. So is it impossible then?

Comment: @TyQ. I think not - as mentioned, I'm about to set values of an external site's forms.

Comment: In the end, you're still changing popup window content as suggested in the title.

Comment: @Canert Unless the site you're trying to modify has some kind of `window.postMessage` API, it is probably not possible unless you use something like a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script to expose a `window.postMessage` API.  This would essentially be a 3rd party script your site's users would have to install, so probably not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

More detail window.open  here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

It is better to use  http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/demos/ or another libs